# Seaborn Heatmap Behavior

Tags: python, seaborn

Consider this code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,5))
sns.heatmap(np.ones((4,4)), ax=ax, cbar=None, cmap="Blues", linewidths=1, linecolor='black')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,5))
sns.heatmap(np.ones((4,4)), ax=ax, cmap="Blues", linewidths=1, linecolor='black')
```

It outputs:

[image: Heatmaps]

Why does adding the argument `cbar=None` change the result of the outcome?

Comment: If all values are the same (here `1`s), there is a free parameter in the determination of the normalization of values to color. Use `vmin`/`vmax` arguments (or `norm` argument), to fix the normalization.

Answer (score 0):

It is the default behavior by `cbar`, some kind of bug.

Turn off `cbar`:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,5))
sns.heatmap(np.ones((4, 4)), ax=ax, cmap='Blues', linewidths=1, linecolor='black', cbar=False, vmin=0, vmax=2)
```

[image]

Turn on `cbar`:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,5))
sns.heatmap(np.ones((4,4)), ax=ax, cmap='Blues', linewidths=1, linecolor='black', cbar=True, vmin=0, vmax=2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As showed by @Alpha, cbar value should be boolean as it can be seen in the [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html)

> **cbar** : boolean, optional
>
> Whether to draw a colorbar.

Answer (score 0):

For both figures to have the same size, you can use:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,5))
sns.heatmap(np.ones((4,4)), ax=ax, linewidths=1, linecolor='black', cmap="Blues",)
cbar = ax.collections[0].colorbar
cbar.remove()
plt.show()
```

[image]

and ...

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,5))
sns.heatmap(np.ones((4,4)), ax=ax, linewidths=1, linecolor='black', cmap="Blues",)
cbar = ax.collections[0].colorbar
#cbar.remove()
plt.show()
```

[image]